# Use PyInstaller or other python commands in a python script

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

I would like to make a script that generates an exe file with pyinstaller from computers that do not necessarily have python installed.

For this, I did something like this:

```
python_script_path = input("Enter the path of the Python file. Ex : C:\\User\\Desktop\\test.py -> ")
subprocess.run(r'python -m pyinstaller {python_script_path}')
```

Of course, when I execute this, I have this error "No module named pyinstaller" even if I actually have PyInstaller on my computer.

So I don't know how to deal with it..

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried `pyinstaller {python_script_path}`? I think `pyinstaller` cannot be invoked using `python -m`

Comment: OKay, that was the solution, thank you !